# React Bootstrap Accordion map() List Items

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

Having trouble rendering data that seeming exists inside an object that is populated inside my App.tsx file upon the home page rendering. The list of data in question:

[image]

This user object containing the list of org reports is then prop drilled down to the component where it needs to be rendered into a bootstrap accordion component.

I set the `props.user._organizationReports` list to a test variable and console log it inside a useEffect call. This logs successfully when my child component renders.

```
const OrgOverviewAccordion: React.FC<OrgOverviewAccordionProps> = props => {
  const test = props.user._organizationReports;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(test);
  }, []);
```

However, when I try to map through the list inside an accordion component, nothing renders when the component is toggled.

parent component:

```
<Accordion.Collapse eventKey="2">
   <OrgOverviewAccordion user={props.user} />  <-------Component
</Accordion.Collapse>
```

child component:

```
.
.
.
return (
{test.map((orgReport: any) => (  <----seems to break here
  <Card.Body key={orgReport.orgName}>
    {console.log('report: ', orgReport)}
    <Row>
      <Col xs={5} className="padReset">
        <p className="font-weight-bold">Org Name:</p>
      </Col>
.
.
.
```

Any idea why mapping through a list in my JSX is causing me issues inside the bootstrap accordion component?

Thanks!

---EDIT---

`App.tsx`:

```
  const [user] = React.useState<User>(new User());

  const handleKeycloakAuth = React.useCallback(async (): Promise<void> => {
    const keycloakResponse = await fetchToken();
    if (keycloakResponse !== KEYCLOAK_ERROR_RESPONSE) {
      user.buildFromKeycloak(keycloakResponse);
      await user.retrieveUserInformation();
      await user.getLastReportByUserId();
      await user.getOrganizationsByProfileId();
      await user.getOrganizationSummaryByOrgId();
      setKeycloak(keycloakResponse);
      setLoggedIn(true);
      localStorage.setItem(LOGGED_IN_KEY, TRUE_STRING);
    }
    localStorage.setItem(CLICKED_LOGIN_KEY, FALSE_STRING);
    setClickedLogin(false);
  }, [setKeycloak, user]);

  console.log(user);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clickedLogin || loggedIn) {
      handleKeycloakAuth();
    }
  }, [clickedLogin, handleKeycloakAuth, loggedIn]);
```

Is it possible that all of the above mentioned child components render before the four `await` functions are finished grabbing data?

Comment: It appears that the components are rendering before the api calls that put together the user object complete. See ---EDIT--- section at bottom.

Comment: Please create working example like https://codesandbox.io/s/old-waterfall-ry7sh for better understanding of the problem..